# How the if() function executes in Azure Resource Manager Templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am using `if()` functions in my ARM template to conditionally set some connection string values in my Web App resource. The current condition looks like this.

```
"[if(equals(parameters('isProduction'), 'Yes'), concat(variables('redisCacheName'),'.redis.cache.windows.net:6380|', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Cache/Redis', variables('redisCacheName')), '2015-08-01').primaryKey, '|', variables('resourcePrefix')), parameters('redisSessionStateConnection'))]"
```

To simplify it, the condition looks like this;

> **[if(equals(arg1, arg2), true_expression, false_expression)]**

When I deploy the ARM template with `isProduction` parameter set to `No` the execution throws an exception. When `isProduction` parameter is set to `Yes` then the template works fine. The exceptions is related to ARM trying to find the redis cache resource which will not be deployed in *non production* environment.

My guess is even if the `isProduction` parameter value is `No`, the **true_expression** in the above condition which is referencing the Redis Cache resource is getting executed and since the *Redis Cache resource is not created in a non production state*, it throws the exception.

So my question is, when we have a condition like above, will the **true_expression** and the **false_expression** in the `if()` function is evaluated before the actual condition of the `if()` function is executed?

If so what would be possible workarounds to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sides of `if()` are evaluated regardless (in ARM templates). so you have to work around that using "clever" ways.

you could use nested deployments\variables to try and work around that.

update: this has been fixed some time ago, only the relevant part of `if()` function is evaluated.

Comment: We're making some changes to this behavior to short circuit the evaluation, it's in code review if you want to check back in a few weeks it should be live.

Comment: hey, is it live yet? i'm dying to use it :( @bmoore-msft

Comment: Ok, I think this has hit all regions now if you want to update your answer ;)

Comment: great, whats next? variables `listkeys()`? runtime properties copy to support resource look with properties loop? `reference()` in `count` property? make arm templates great :) @bmoore-msft

Comment: can you add jmespath query support, that would be so much better, tbh @bmoore-msft and should be pretty easy. there should be a lib for that, probably

Comment: this is super awesome.. I really didn't want to go for any other messy solution for this.. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Throw an item in UserVoice - that's the best way to stack 'em.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be: <s>no, only the</s> yes, both expressions <s>needed based on the outcome of the if statement is</s> are evaluated.

To solve your issue: you can use environment specific parameter files. This enables you to only include parameters for the environment you're deploying to.

See the [documentation on parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#parameters) in the 'Understand the structure and syntax of Azure Resource Manager templates' article.

> In the parameters section of the template, you specify which values you can input when deploying the resources. These parameter values enable you to customize the deployment by providing values that are tailored for a particular environment (such as dev, test, and production). You do not have to provide parameters in your template, but without parameters your template would always deploy the same resources with the same names, locations, and properties.

Comment: this is not true :)

Comment: I already have environment specific parameter files. I wanted to reference the Redis Cache resource and construct the connection string instead of having the connection string in the parameter file.