# if() function evaluates both expressions in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm using the if() function in a copy operation for an Azure KeyVault:

```
"variables": {
    "users": 3,
    "user1": {
        "tenantId": "[variables('tenantId')]",
        "objectId": "abcd",
        "permissions": {
            "keys": [
                "get"
            ],
            "secrets": [
                "get"
            ],
            "certificates": [
                "get"
            ]
        }
    },

    "user2": {
        "tenantId": "[variables('tenantId')]",
        "objectId": "efgh",
        "permissions": {
            "keys": [
                "get"
            ],
            "secrets": [
                "get"
            ],
            "certificates": [
                "get"
            ]
        }
    },

    "user3": {
        "tenantId": "[variables('tenantId')]",
        "objectId": "ijkl",
        "permissions": {
            "secrets": [
                "get"
            ]
        }
    },

    "extraUsers": [
        "[variables('user1')]",
        "[variables('user2')]",
        "[variables('user3')]"
    ]

"resources": [
    {
        "name": "myKeyVault",
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
        "location": "some_location",
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "KeyVault"
        },
        "properties": {
            "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "accessPolicies",
                    "count": "[add(variables('users'), length(variables('extraUsers')))]",
                    "input": {
                        "tenantId": "[variables('tenantId')]",
                        "objectId": "[if(less(copyIndex('myLoop'), variables('users')), reference(concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVm', copyIndex('myLoop'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId, variables('extraUsers')[sub(copyIndex('myLoop'), variables('users'))].objectId)]",
                        "permissions": "[if(less(copyIndex('myLoop'), variables('users')), json($null), variables('extraUsers')[sub(copyIndex('myLoop'), variables('users'))].permissions)]"
                    }
                }
            ],
```

The above boils down to:

```
if((index < A), <some object>.principalId, myArray[index - A].objectId)
```

However, when I try to deploy it, I get an error that an index of -1 is not allowed.  It seems that ARM evaluates both the true and false expressions, so of course the subtract operation produces a negative result in the false expression.

However, according to the answer here, this should be fixed in all regions:

[How the if() function executes in Azure Resource Manager Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445384/how-the-if-function-executes-in-azure-resource-manager-templates)

Anyone know why this is happening?

I did notice that the latest API version for the AKV resource in ARM templates is 2018-02-14, which is well before when bmoore-msft in the above question mentions the bug was fixed.  I'm not sure if the API version is an accurate indicator of when code was released, or if it's just a label.

Comment: can you share variables?

Comment: Yes, if you can complete the repro will be helpful to see if we have a bug here...

Comment: Thanks.  I've added the inputs.  They've been simplified where I don't think the details are relevant (i.e., objectId).  I also didn't include the managed identity resource, as I don't think it is part of the issue.  In the repro, you can replace its principalId with some dummy value.

Comment: @bmoore-msft: Any update?

Comment: Sorry I missed the SO notification... to be clear, are you using that accessPolicy copy in the variables section or on the KeyVault resource?  Also, feel free to email me - bmoore at msft if I go dark again.

Comment: I'm using the accessPolicy copy on the KeyVault resource.  I've updated my question to make this clearer.  In case it matters, the KeyVault itself already exists.

Comment: ok, I wanna say that should work - let me try something and get back to you...

Comment: @bmoore-msft: Did it work out?

Comment: yes and no - I'll post a new answer since it won't fit here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried again and it works now.  I did discover some syntax errors in my code.  I originally wrote:

```
"copy": [
    {
         "name": "loopName",
         "count": 3,
         "input": {
             "name": accessPolicies",
             "properties": { /* accessPolicies properties */ }
         }
    }
]
```

I thought that copy.name was the name of the loop, and that copy.input.name was the name of the property to copy.  In fact it should be:

```
"copy": [
    {
        "name": accessPolicies",
         "count": 3,
         "input": {
             /* accessPolicies properties */
         }
    }
]
```

The loop doesn't have a name.  You just supply the name of the property to copy.  I've updated the code in my question.

However, even if I revert to the original wrong version, I don't get the same error about a negative index.  Instead I get an error that a bad value was provided for "accessPolicies".  So unfortunately, I'm not sure what was the root cause.  It may have been my syntax error, some server-side issue, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

it means your condition evaluates to not what you think it evaluates. api version doesnt matter. also, this is the part that evaluates to -1 (as far as I understand):

```
sub(copyIndex('myLoop'), variables('users'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem you're running into is that vars are evaluated before copy and copy is evaluated before if - so you still need valid indexes in an if() statement.  We might be able to fix that, but for the short-term you need another approach.  In your case, because you have exactly 2 batches and you're creating the vault, you can you an addition "pass" on the vault to add more access policies.

Essentially you can first create the vault and add the MSI access policies and then after that's finished you can add the extra users.  If you needed more than 2 "passes" or you're not creating the vault, then you would have to use nested deployments to do multiple passes (which works, it's just more work).

Here's a sample based on your snippet above:

```
        {
        "name": "myKeyVault",
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
        "location": "some_location",
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "KeyVault"
        },
        "properties": {
            "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "myLoop",
                    "count": "[variables('users')]",
                    "input": {
                        "name": "accessPolicies",
                        "properties": {
                            "tenantId": "[variables('tenantId')]",
                            "objectId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVm', copyIndex('myLoop'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]",
                            "permissions": "[json('null')]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[concat('myKeyVault', '/add')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
        "location": "some_location",
        "dependsOn": [
            "myKeyVault"
        ],
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "MoreAccessPolicies"
        },
        "properties": {
            "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "myLoop2",
                    "count": "[length(variables('extraUsers'))]",
                    "input": {
                        "name": "accessPolicies",
                        "properties": {
                            "tenantId": "[variables('tenantId')]",
                            "objectId": "[variables('extraUsers')[copyIndex('myLoop2')].objectId]",
                            "permissions": "[variables('extraUsers')[copyIndex('myLoop2')].permissions]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

That help?

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  I got my original code working.  I've posted an answer.